# ascii enter key return 0 through javascript in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, submit, form-submit

I am trying to submit a form through Javascript with a simple code. When user press **Enter key** form should submit.

My code works on chrome, safari and ie , but it does not work on **FireFox** . It's better to say **charCode** attribute from event object return 0 instead 13.

**JS Works on Chrome and the others :**

```
var up = document.getElementById('up');
    var handler = function(e){
        if(e.charCode == 13){
            document.getElementById("sendForm").submit();
        }

    }
    up.keypress = addEventListener('keypress',handler);
```

**JS Works on FireFox**

```
var up = document.getElementById('up');
        var handler = function(e){
            if(e.charCode == 0){
                document.getElementById("sendForm").submit();
            }

        }
        up.keypress = addEventListener('keypress',handler);
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" id='sendForm' action='http://google.com'>
     <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id='up'></textarea> 
    <input type='submit' name='sub'>
</form
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use keypress and e.charCode use keydown and e.keyCode. That will get you "13" across all browsers for "Enter".

Comment: well, that's work! thanks :) , but why? because first ascii code burnt then keycode :)

Comment: You use charCode when you need to get the actual character of the key the user typed. It is not standard across browsers for non-character keys.

Comment: Also, please accept the answer if it worked for you. :)

Comment: so thanks. 15 reputations need for voting up :| I am really sorry :|

Comment: From stackoverflow help ... To accept an answer:

Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.

Comment: :) Thanks again :) I made an mistake between accept & useful :|